# REPLACE and IF in expression causes concatenation from previous row

Tags: mysql, if-statement, replace

The following sql statement:

```
SELECT 
    profile_pic
FROM
    (`member`) 
WHERE 
    `active` = 1
```

produces the following result:

```
profile_pic
    1_1345694557.jpg
    <blank_value>
    <blank_value>
    <blank_value>
```

I want the "blank values" to default to "no_prof_thumb.jpg".

So I created this statement:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(IF (CHAR_LENGTH(profile_pic) > 0, profile_pic, 'no_prof.jpg' ), '.jpg', '_thumb.jpg') AS profile_pic 
FROM 
    (`member`) 
WHERE 
    `active` = 1
```

Here is the result:

```
profile_pic
1_1345694557_thumb.jpg
no_prof_thumb.jpg
no_prof_thumb_thumb.jpg
no_prof_thumb_thumb_thumb.jpg
```

Why does `_thumb` keep appending itself to the value in the previous row?

How should I fix my expression?

---

## Update

This issue occurs on a GoDaddy mySQL database.  I reproduce when it connecting remotely through SQLyog and when I log into GoDaddy and run it through phpMyAdmin.

However, I cannot reproduce locally nor on sqlFiddle.
So it must be some kind of configuration issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to use `IF` outside the `REPLACE` statement like this.

```
SELECT 
    IF (profile_pic = '', 'no_prof.jpg', 
        REPLACE(profile_pic, '.jpg', '_thumb.jpg')) AS profile_pic 
FROM 
    (`member`) 
WHERE 
    `active` = 1
```

You can also use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) statement instead of `IF` like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE  profile_pic
    WHEN '' THEN 'no_prof.jpg'
    ELSE REPLACE(profile_pic, '.jpg', '_thumb.jpg')
  END AS profile_pic
FROM member
WHERE active = 1;
```

## [*See this fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fb8d/13)

Comment: I reproduced this issue on a GoDaddy mysql database.  I tested the sql on sqlfiddle and locally and could not reproduce.  So, it must be some kind of configuration issue on their servers.  Your suggestion works though.  Ty.

Answer (score 1):

The nested logic is a little weird. You can simplify it with a `CASE` statement.  If the value is an empty string, just return `no_prof_thumb.jpg`. Otherwise, replace `.jpg` with `_thumb.jpg`.

```
SELECT
  CASE  
    WHEN profile_pic = '' THEN 'no_prof_thumb.jpg'
    ELSE REPLACE(profile_pic, '.jpg', '_thumb.jpg')
  END AS profile_pic
FROM member
WHERE active = 1
```

I can't, explain why you're getting the weird result you're getting without further testing though.

Comment: small syntax issue:  closing parenthesis on REPLACE.  Otherwise, it works.